# DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener called twice

Tags: android, events, datepicker

I'm trying to create an app where the user selects a date from a DatePicker, and then a list is updated with some values.

My GUI looks like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >


    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >


    </ListView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Whereas my DatePicker initialization and handling look as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    datePicker.init(year, month, day, dateSetListener);
}

private DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener dateSetListener = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
         System.out.println ("TEST");

    }
};
```

In CatLog I see that "TEST" string is output twice, each time I play with the +/- buttons on the widget. What could be the problem?

Note: I've "disabled" the list-updating code on purpose, in order to make sure that the problem is not related to the ListView, as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553849/android-why-ondatechange-callback-is-called-twice)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

When I test my application, method onDateSet called twice after accept the date selection and once when I canceled.

I added a validation in the method onDateSet with parameter view, something like this

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
    if (view.isShown()) {
        updateDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bug which has been fixed in Android 5.0, there is no backport for earlier version. So use this workaround. Bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34833

Comment: If we use above code, is there any problem above android 5.0 devices?

Answer (score 9):

I still haven't managed to find a neat fix. I've rather found a workaround, so the event does not fire twice. The workaround is as follows:

```
int timesCalled = 1;

private DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener dateSetListener = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
     timesCalled += 1;

     if ((timesCalled % 2) == 0) {
        System.out.println ("TEST");
     }

}};
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the onDateSet callback I've overridden onClick method of the DatePickerDialog dialog and handle BUTTON_POSITIVE clicks only.

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int initialYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int initialMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int initialDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), null, initialYear, initialMonth, initialDay) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                    int year = getDatePicker().getYear();
                    int month = getDatePicker().getMonth();
                    int day = getDatePicker().getDayOfMonth();

                    //TODO: Do your logic here
                }
                super.onClick(dialog, which);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The code stays clear but still it's not clear why onDateSet is called twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
private DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener dateSetListener = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() { 

    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, 
            int dayOfMonth) { 
         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
         c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth); 
         updateDisplay();

    } 
}; 


TextView datetext;
datetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_date);


private void updateDisplay() {
        this.datetext.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not seem to solve my problem. I am not having issues with updating the display. Rather, I am having the display updated twice, instead of once.

Comment: Try this...    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { public void onDateSet(

Comment: The problem is that datePicker.init accepts as a last parameter a DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener, not DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, hence it is not working :S

Comment: I came to find out that the problem was not associated with updating the view but was something to do with when the dialog is being created, so if is to control the effect then the solution lies with controlling the dialog creation and visibility depending on which method do you use to populate the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps modify the listener by adding instance variables, that way you can check to see if they are different from the last time the method was called:

```
final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog (this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
    {   
        private int year;
        private int month;
        private int day;

        @Override
        public void onDateSet (DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            if (this.year == year && this.month == monthOfYear && this.day == dayOfMonth)
                return;

            this.year = year;
            this.month = monthOfYear;
            this.day = dayOfMonth;

            calendar.set (year, month, day);
            int index = officeCalendar.indexOfKey (calendar.getTimeInMillis ());

            if (index > -1)
                viewPager.setCurrentItem (index);
        }
    }, calendar.get (Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get (Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get (Calendar.DATE));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener dateSetListener = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
    boolean fired = false;
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
         if (fired == true){
//Twince
         }
         else{
             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
             c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
             System.out.println ("TEST");
         }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to add this code under Jelly beans

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
    if (view.isShown()) {
        updateDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a SupportDatePickerDialog.kt class

```kotlin
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog
    import android.content.Context
    import android.os.Build
    import android.widget.DatePicker
    import androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
    
    /**
     * Support [DatePickerDialog]
     * for working around Samsung 5 [java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException] bug.
     * > Fatal Exception: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format java.lang.String arguments
     * http://stackoverflow.com/a/31855744/570168
     * for OnDateSetListener called twice bug
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436073/datepicker-ondatechangedlistener-called-twice
     *
     */
    
    
    
    class SupportDateSetListener(private val function: (DatePicker, Int, Int, Int) -> Unit) : DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
            if (view.isShown) {
                function.invoke(view, year, month, dayOfMonth)
            }
        }
    }
    
    class SupportDatePickerDialog(context: Context, listener: SupportDateSetListener, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) : DatePickerDialog(fixContext(context), listener, year, month, dayOfMonth) {
        companion object {
            /**
             * Wraps the [Context] to use the holo theme to avoid stupid bug on Samsung devices.
             */
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            private fun fixContext(context: Context): Context {
                return if (isBrokenSamsungDevice) {
                    ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog)
                } else {
                    context
                }
            }
    
            /**
             * Affected devices:
             * - Samsung 5.0
             * - Samsung 5.1
             *
             * @return true if device is affected by this bug.
             */
            @Suppress("SpellCheckingInspection")
            private val isBrokenSamsungDevice: Boolean
                get() = (Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("samsung", ignoreCase = true)
                        && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
        }
    }
```

Usage :

```kotlin
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val supportDatePickerDialog = SupportDatePickerDialog(this, SupportDateSetListener { datePicker: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
    //TODO
}, calendar[Calendar.YEAR], calendar[Calendar.MONTH], calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH])

supportDatePickerDialog.show()
```