# onDateChanged in onclick fires after two clicks that is when i click third time on ok button

Tags: android, datepicker

Hi everyone I am getting an error that `onClick` fires after i click two times, i want it to be performed on first click . Here in this code i took one date-picker to display date, on user selecting one date and press ok button that date must be displayed in TextView.

this is **My Code**

```
public class TimePicker extends Activity{
protected static OnDateChangedListener OnDateChangedListener;
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
private String Date;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.time_picker);   
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);      


    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            OnDateChangedListener = new OnDateChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker v, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    year = selectedYear;
                    month = selectedMonth;
                    day = selectedDay;
                }
            };  
            dp.init(year, month, day, OnDateChangedListener);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(day).append("-").append(month+1).append("-").append(year);
            Date = sb.toString();
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
            txt.setText(Date);  
        }
    });
```

}
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener called twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436073/datepicker-ondatechangedlistener-called-twice)

Comment: Here my problem is not firing upto two times i click on ok button after third time i click on ok button it shows... there is huge difference

Answer (score 1):

Move this line `dp.init(year, month, day, OnDateChangedListener);` below the `OnDateChangedListener` instantiation. it gets invoked the 2nd time because the 1st time it was just initiated.

You should also make `txt` into a field and call `setText` within `OnDateChanged` after assigning `Date` its new value. remove the call to `setText` within `onClick`.

i.e.

```
OnDateChangedListener = new OnDateChangedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDateChanged(DatePicker v, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       year = selectedYear;
       month = selectedMonth;
       day = selectedDay;
       displayDate();
    }
};

dp.init(year, month, day, OnDateChangedListener);

displayDate();
```

You can create a method for populating the `txt` field:

```
private void displayDate() {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(day).append("-").append(month+1).append("-").append(year);
   Date = sb.toString();
   TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
   txt.setText(Date);  
}
```

Comment: I don't even think that's enough. *most* of the code in the onClick() block needs to be moved out, all but the last two lines in fact.

Comment: i moved like that and tested, getting current system date that i initiated through calendar

Comment: i want each and everytime i click on ok button the updated date by user

Comment: @kyle   After keeping DatePicker.init below the OnDateChangedListener it modifies .. on second click only my expected output comes but on first click it displays system date in textview and as well as it modifies in datePicker if we changed date.

Comment: @naveen please include the code for your `dp.init` method.

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel Hai i just now updated my code now it works on second click as i init dropped after onDateChanged . but i need it to be on first click...Thanks for everything.

Comment: @naveen I've updated my answer. please check again. thanks

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel Even though the first click displays system current date...should call any other OnDateSetChange or anything ...